# N*N sized Identity Matrix using Higher Order Functions

Tags: javascript, arrays, higher-order-functions

I am trying to create an `n * n` **identity matrix** using only the methods in the `Array.prototype` (you are welcome to call other methods). I can create an `n*n` matrix using `fill()` but have trouble converting the diagonal elements into **1** without using `if-else`.

```js
function matrix(n) {
  var nSizeArray = Array(n).fill().map(function(elem) {
    return Array(elem).fill(0).indexOf([elem][elem]=1)
  })
  return nSizeArray
}
matrix(5)
```

The above is just some demonstration of what I wished to do. I can't wrap my head around how to keep filling the array and accessing the `[i][i]` element in an array using the available array methods.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with else-if.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Oh well, I just saw that you wrote *only the methods in the Array.prototype* not just *only functions*... So I'm guessing you don't want to include `Math` functions either?

The second parameter to the `map` is the index of the element, which we will use to fill the correct spots in the matrix with `1`s.

Now we need a way to assign a `1` at every position with `i == j` and a `0` at every other position without using the obvious `if..else` approach. We can use the fact that `i == j` is equivalent to `i - j == 0`.

So now the task is to map every `(i,j)` with `i - j == 0` to `1` and `i - j != 0` to `0`.

We do this using this line:

```
return 1 - Math.min(Math.abs(i-j),1);
```

The `Math.min(...)` ensures that `i - j == 0` is mapped to `0` and all other index combinations are mapped to `1` (since they result in `|i-j| >= 1`). By subtracting this result from `1` we can simply flip the *bit* and get our desired result:

```js
function matrix(n) {
  return Array(n).fill(0).map(function(elem, i) {
    return Array(n).fill(0).map(function(elem2, j) {
      return 1 - Math.min(Math.abs(i-j),1);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: I was onto something similar but stumbled upon something that i couldn't explain. maybe you could help. why is the inner map not doing anything? https://jsfiddle.net/4e7nh6vz/1/

Comment: derp... figured it out... map doesn't modify the source array itself, it just returns the modified one

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following function to create an **`n * n` identity matrix**:

```js
const eye = n => [...Array(n)].map((e, i, a) => a.map(e => +!i--));

console.log(eye(3));

// [ [ 1, 0, 0 ],
//   [ 0, 1, 0 ],
//   [ 0, 0, 1 ] ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with:

```
function matrix(n) {
    return Array(n).fill(Array(n).fill())
    .map(function (xs, i) {
        return xs.map(function (x, j) {
            return i === j ? 1 : 0;
        })
    });
}
matrix(5)
```

If you don't use if else (or ternary operation), the result will be a boleean matrix.

Comment: I felt using `Array::fill` is more modern (and more in line with the OPs original code). Feel free to rollback the edit if you think it's too intrusive

Answer (score 0):

I done that example with ES6 function.

```js
function Matrix(n) {
  return [...Array(n)].map((e1, x, arr) => arr.map((e2, y) => (x === y ? 1 : 0)));
}
console.log(Matrix(5));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getIdentityMatrix(n) {
   let index=0;
   let arr=new Array(n).fill(0);
   arr.map(x=>{
      let tmp=new Array(n).fill(0);
      tmp[index]=1;
      arr[index++]=tmp;
      return x;
   });
   return arr;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
function getIdentityMatrix(n) {
  let index = 0;
  const arr = new Array(n).fill(0);
  arr.map((x) => {
    const tmp = new Array(n).fill(0);
    tmp[index] = 1;
    arr[index += 1] = tmp;
    return x;
  });
  return arr.slice(1);
}
```